# Different DNS resolution for same domain name

Tags: ip-address, dns

I am getting different DNS resolution for www.google.com.

When I am using Google Public DNS i.e 8.8.8.8 then by using nslookup then it is giving IP address of

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.217.26.228
```

But when I am using my internet provider DNS Server in my case JIO network DNS Server then I am getting a different resolution of

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 216.58.196.68
```

I am not understanding how this is happening? Do we have different entries for Domain names with different vendors of DNS Servers? SOUNDS WEIRD!!

Comment: This is quite possible, especially with a distributed service provider like Google. IP addresses may be resolved depending on geolocation, load, .... However, questions about networks outside your control are off-topic here.